# Command like \vspace*{} but applied to current line

Tags: spacing

So within a paragraph putting `\vspace*{-2pt}` in a line raises the next line (and the following ones) by 2 pt. Is there a way of having it apply to the current line instead?

For now, what I've got is `\raisebox{2pt}{current line}\vspace*{-2pt}`, but that's not very elegant and it doesn't work if the current line is the first of a paragraph (I thought adding `\leavevmode` would fix that, but it doesn't always).

Comment: You can try adding a strut to the current line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\vspace is implemented with \vadjust, which inserts vertical material after the current line. If you use a modern TeX engine \vadjust can be given the option `pre` to insert the material before the current line. To use this with `\vspace`, you can temporarily redefine `\vadjust` to always use `pre`. Write

```
\let\realvadjust\vadjust
\def\vadjustpre{\realvadjust pre}
\newcommand\vprespace[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\vadjust\vadjustpre
  \vspace*{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

In your preamble, then you can use `\vprespace{-2pt}`  to move the current line(and all following).

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but I'm getting the error:Missing { inserted\\Missing } inserted. And if I compile anyway it prints "-2pt" at the end of the line instead of adjusting the height...

Comment: @Alexbib Sorry, there was a typo in the command. Now it should work.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know this (or had forgetten it ...).